# Linux socket buffered data size

Tags: linux, sockets, buffer

Is there any simple functions to check how much data is buffered but unread? FD_ISSET only indicates the presence of data in the buffer. Is possible not to create a second buffer in the program for greater control of buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `recv()` with the `MSG_PEEK` and `MSG_DONTWAIT` flags, but there's no firm guarantee that there aren't *more* bytes available than `recv()` returned in that case.

Using a buffer within your program is the normal and accepted way to solve the problem.

Comment: This helps a lot! Although peek move the data one more time, it let me quickly test the system buffer usage. I decide create a thread to move the data from system buffer to program buffer.